# Is there any gtk-editor where you can limit characters to 80 columns in a single file?

Tags: text-processing, editors, gtk

I have been looking at multiple gtk-editors. To name a few, gedit, leafpad and mousepad. Neither of them has support for limiting 80 characters on a single line.

Although nano, a command-line tool has that if I set it like this in ~/.nanorc

[$] cat .nanorc

```
 1  set autoindent
 2  set backup
 3  set constantshow
 4  set fill 80
```

While others are just prettifying, the functional one which I'm talking about is line 4 - `set fill 80` which makes sure that if I go over 80 characters a line, the content automatically shifts to the next line.

Now does anybody of any gtk-editor which does that ?

Comment: `gvim` will do the trick with a similarly-configured `.vimrc`.  I'm pretty sure Atom can also, but I don't believe it to be a gtk application.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there's Emacs. It can be built with Gtk.

The Emacs equivalent of Nano's `set fill 80` is [`(setq fill-column 80)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fill-Commands.html#index-fill_002dcolumn) (see [How to set the default width of fill mode to 80 with emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566727/how-to-set-the-default-width-of-fill-mode-to-80-with-emacs)) plus turning on [Auto Fill mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Fill.html#Auto-Fill). There's no command to turn on Auto Fill mode by default because there are many types of files (e.g. program source code) for which is is not appropriate. Turning it on for Text mode covers most cases where it can be desirable:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
```

See also [the Emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoFillMode).